# Undo setup done using NavigationUI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-architecture-components

I have setup drawer using NavigationUI

```
 NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, drawerLayout)
 NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController)
```

How can i remove/un-link the drawerLayout and toolbar from navController?

Comment: What are you doing that you feel that you need to unlink the drawerlayout and toolbar?

Comment: Nothing productive or work related, just playing with Navigation Components,
Exploring the possible use cases etc.

Like what if later on I want to change the UI from  DrawerLayout to BottomNav view etc

Answer (score 0):

NavigationUI keeps a `WeakReference` to the `Toolbar` and `DrawerLayout` you pass into it, automatically cleaning up the listeners when any of the underlying views are garbage collected (say, if your `Toolbar` is part of a Fragment's layout). There should be no need to manually unregister a listener set with NavigationUI and there's no API to do it if you did want to do it.